Detecting Browser Event (blur, visibilitychange etc) Blocking by Third-Party Applications in Next.js (Version 13)
I'm developing a web application using Next.js version 13 that includes critical browser events like blur and fullscreenchange . These events are essential for user interaction, but they can be blocked by third-party browser extensions or applications. I need to detect programmatically if these events are being blocked by any third-party software.
Context:
I'm aware that some browser extensions, like Luminous, can interfere with these events.
The application relies on these events for essential functionality, such as preventing navigation away during assessments.
My code?
document.addEventListener("blur", () => {
    console.log("focus");
    alert("focus");
  });

This code is getting blocked by extension 
Question:
What is the standard approach or technique to detect whether browser events (blur, fullscreenchange, etc.) are blocked by third-party applications or browser extensions in a Next.js application? Are there specific JavaScript methods or libraries that can help in detecting such interference?
I have tried every possible solution to detect but no success.
Any suggestions or code examples will be appreciated.
Thanks for your time.
